# The following packages have unmet dependencies. mysql-workbench-community

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

You might want to run `apt-get -f install` to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies.

```
mysql-workbench-community : Depends: libcairo2 (>= 1.15.8) but 1.14.6-1 is installed
                             Depends: libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (>= 2.54.0) but 2.46.3-1 is installed
                             Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.5) but 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3 is installed
                             Depends: libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 (>= 3.22.0) but 3.18.0-1 is installed
                             Depends: libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (>= 2.40.0) but 2.38.1-1 is installed
                             Depends: libpcrecpp0v5 (>= 7.7) but it is not installed
                             Depends: libpng16-16 (>= 1.6.2-1) but it is not installed
                             Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.8.0) but 2.6.2-1 is installed
                             Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
                             Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 7) but 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10 is installed
                             Depends: libvsqlitepp3v5 (>= 0.3.13) but it is not installed
                             Depends: libzip4 (>= 0.10) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: Tried apt-get -f install    still not working

Comment: What is the initial command you run when getting this error?

Comment: Looks like you have introduced a *version conflict* by trying to install a wrong-version package. The package's dependencies are incompatible with the rest of your system (that's what all those 'Depends:' lines are trying to tell you - read them!) Rather like using a bicycle tire of wrong diameter, simply uninstall the wrong-version package to fix the problem.

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy mysql-workbench-community` to the question. There is no such official Ubuntu package [in the repos](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=mysql-workbench-community).

Comment: @Rupeshpanneerselvam What version of Ubuntu you are using?